# Ubunu 18.04 server, unable to login to server

Tags: server, 18.04, ssh

I am trying to setup an Ubuntu server for the first time. I have followed [this guide](https://www.virtualzero.net/blog/how-to-install-ubuntu-server-18.04-lts-in-virtualbox) to install Ubuntu 18.04 within a virtual machine.

I then followed [this guide](https://arador.com/how-to-configure-a-static-ip-address-in-ubuntu-18-04/) to configure a static ip, which seems to have worked fine:

[image]

I am now trying to follow [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-18-04) to set the server up, however I am failing at step one logging in as root. I use `ssh root@192.168.1.70` and am prompted for the password and have entered the one I set during the installation, however that is not accepted.

I've assumed that this is the password I should be entering as I have not set any other password. Is this logic correct? Or what should I be entering here? Assuming I have done everything else correctly.

Comment: Password-based login for the root account is normally disabled - you should log in using the credentials you supplied in Step 19

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver, I login initially using those credentials. Now the guide I am following is saying to enter `ssh root@your_server_ip`, should the password required be the same as the password from step 19 or should I not be doing this at all?

Comment: The second guide that you linked appears to be specific to DigitalOcean droplets - these may be configured to use `root` out of the box. Vanilla Ubuntu doesn't do that.

Comment: Okay, so I will need to use DigitalOcean droplets in order to follow that guide?

Answer (score 3):

**I don't think what you're trying to do is actually possible with a fresh install.**

By default, the root account is accessed by sudo. Password for root **is not set** in Ubuntu which means the root login is disabled by default. This is *good security practice* to not permit remote logins to root on your system.

To login, leverage the *username* and *password* you provided during the install to login as that user, then `sudo su -` if you *really want* to run as root.

Comment: Even if a password is set for `root` (allowing *local* root login), the default `sshd_config` doesn't allow password-based authentication IIRC (it sets `PermitRootLogin` to `prohibit-password`)